# NestJS dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

I have a service that consumes messages from a queue and depending on `type` in the message I want to init a service.
For example for a message `{ "type": "A" }` I want to use `ServiceA`, for a message `{ "type": "B" }` I want to use `ServiceB`.
Both `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` extends `abstract BaseService`.

How can I inject NestJS `Injectable` into `ServiceA`?

Comment: I think I used to be in a similar scenario when I had to create two services with the same footprint but with different configurations. (To be more specific: a service which implements an abstraction of Elasticsearch SDK)... Using dynamic providers I've created two modules which implements the same codebase of the service with the "useClass" but with two different tokens. More information can be found in the Dynamic Provider section in NestJS official docs. I think it's gonna be way more simpler than applying OOP logic using abstraction classes.

Comment: maybe [`moduleRef`](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/module-ref) could be another solution

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, both services must be initialized so you could refer to the in the runtime. I would recommend you create a common custom provider that aggregates all these handler services together and provide it to the module. This way you could inject this custom provider only and have all the handlers available.

```js
//provider

@Injectable()
export class HandlerService {
    constructor(private handlers: BaseService[]) {}

    public handle(message: any): any {
        // define your handler logic here and apply handler from the handlers array
    }
}
```

```js
//module

@Module({
    providers: [
        ServiceA,
        ServiceB,
        {
          provide: 'HANDLER_SERVICE',
          useFactory: (...handlers) => new HandlerService(handlers),
          inject: [ServiceA, ServiceB],
        },
    ],
})
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid initialising all the services, but apparently there is no way. The way you wrote it is probably the most elegant to do. I will check it and write back.

Answer (score 0):

For example you have methods in you service that you want to use in your controller with requests methods.

I used it this way:

in `user.service.ts`

```js
    @Injectable()
    export class UserService {  

    public getAllUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
      return User.find();
    }
```

and you Inject it inside Controller with @Inject() decorator like so:

in `user.controller.ts`

```js
    @Controller('users')
    export class UserController {
      constructor(
        @Inject(UserService) private readonly userService: UserService,
      ) {}
```

and now you can use UserService methods in your UserController e.g.:

```js
    @Get()
    public getAllUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
      return this.userService.getAllUsers();
    }
```

Remember to import all required decorators (@Inject, @Injectable, @Get etc.)